# How to create a customizable group of hierarchical structure of strings and show it on a page?

Tags: views

I have a group of strings which are to be shown in a hierarchical structure on a Page. They are **not** related to navigation but I am trying to create them like a menu so that the structure can be edited from the admin panel. I have two questions:

1) What is it called in Drupal's language (whatever I try to write it ends looking for menu navigation only)? That's why I am explicitly mentioning it that it is not related to navigation of a the site.

2) Is there a module which can help me create a tree like structure to show it a page? I have to show it using nested accordions.